# Never claim does not work in promela model

Tags: verification, model-checking, spin, promela

Consider this simple PROMELA model:

```
#define p (x!=4)

int x = 0;

init {
    do
    :: x < 10 ->
        x++;
    od
}
```

I wanted to verify this model with this simple claim, which was generated by using spin -f:

```
never {    /* []p */
accept_init:
T0_init:
    do
    :: ((p)) -> goto T0_init
    od;
}
```

However, the verification using

```
spin -a model.pml
cc -o pan pan.c
./pan
```

yields no result. Trying the -a option also does not deliver results.
Any random simulation shows, that obviously p is false at some point, so why does the never claim not work, despite I generated it with spin?

Am I missing something fundamental?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check `[]p`, you will need to construct a `never` claim for `![]p`.

From the [reference](http://spinroot.com/spin/Man/never.html):

> To translate an LTL formula into a never claim, we have to consider first whether the formula expresses a positive or a negative property. A positive property expresses a good behavior that we would like our system to have. A negative property expresses a bad behavior that we claim the system does not have. A never claim is normally only used to formalize negative properties (behaviors that should never happen), which means that positive properties must be negated before they are translated into a claim.

Answer (score 1):

put the claim in the source code (say, check.pml)

```
int x = 0;

init {
    do
    :: x < 10 ->
        x++;
    od
}

ltl  { [] (x != 4) }
```

then

```
spin -a check.pml
cc     pan.c   -o pan
./pan -a
```

this gives

```
pan:1: assertion violated  !( !((x!=4))) (at depth 16)
pan: wrote check.pml.trail
```

you can watch the trail with

```
./pan -r -v
```

IMHO, using an extra tool to construct the automaton from the claim is terribly inconvenient and often confusing.

Comment: "extra tool" is "spin -f LTL" ?